# Signing out from Firebase inside class

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to Flutter and I am trying to implement a page with a drawer. This page is the first page to be shown after the user is logged in using Firebase authentication.
As you may see, there is a logout button at the appbar, it logs out the user calling method _signOut(). But what I need is to implement the same behaviour on all pages that are linked to the drawer options, in this case, FirstPage and SecondPage.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_login_demo/services/authentication.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.auth, this.userId, this.onSignedOut})
      : super(key: key);

  final BaseAuth auth;
  final VoidCallback onSignedOut;
  final String userId;


  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {




  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  }


  _signOut() async {
    try {
      await widget.auth.signOut();
      widget.onSignedOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        drawer: new DrawerOnly(),

      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Drawer Demo"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
              child: new Text('Logout',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)),
              onPressed: _signOut)
        ],
      ),

      body: new Text("Drawer Body"),
    );
  }
}
class DrawerOnly extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new DrawerHeader(
              child: new Text("DRAWER HEADER.."),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.orange
              ),
            ),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text("Item => 1"),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(ctxt);
                Navigator.push(ctxt,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new FirstPage()));
              },
            ),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text("Item => 2"),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(ctxt);
                Navigator.push(ctxt,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new SecondPage()));
              },
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
      drawer: new DrawerOnly(),    // new Line
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("First Page"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
              child: new Text('Logout',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)),

               )
        ],
      ),
      body: new Text("I belongs to First Page"),
    );
  }

}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
      drawer: new DrawerOnly(),    // New Line
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Second Page"),),
      body: new Text("I belongs to Second Page"),
    );
  }
}
```